# KiCAD - Design rules for fabrication boardhouse

Tags: pcb, pcb-fabrication, kicad, board

This is my first time designing a PCB with KiCAD.

I plan to send them to JLCPCB for assembly.

There are a ton of parameters to be set like track width, via width etc.

If these are set wrong, then the boardhouse cannot accept the Gerber files for fabrication.

Would the default values from KiCAD work, or do I have to set up specific parameters?

I ask because I think it's better to have this issue fixed early, and having the correct values set up from the beginning, before trying to fix things later.

Comment: Of course, you need the settings acceptable to your manufacturer.  Some may provide you guidance for setting those in KiCAD, in other cases you will have to understand their requirements and manually enter them in appropriate fields; in a few cases that might even require numerical transformations.

Comment: [This guy has collections of KiCAD templates for projects for various fabrication houses, including JLCPCB.](https://github.com/sethhillbrand/kicad_templates)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default values in KiCAD are pretty generous.  I have yet to use a boardhouse that rejects boards using those values.

In general, you can use tighter tolerances, based on your boardhouse of choice.  These are worth setting up ahead of time because they can make your board layout go much easier if you can get away with smaller, tighter, traces.